# Abinitio configuration file in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, config, ab-initio

We have a Abinitio graph in On-prem, which relies on a configuration file to get few key inputs. To migrate this graph to AWS, we are looking for a better way to handle this configuration info.

This configuration info will be setup one time and it will get updated by other Abinitio process in runtime.

Below are more details:

**Sample Configuration file:-**

```
vi test.dat
Active_Flag|Y
Compress_File|N
Cut_Off_Date|20231231
```

**Graph parameters relying on the Configuration File:-**

```
COMPRESS_FLAG : $(cat test.dat| grep Compress_File | awk -F'|' '{print $2}'
CUT_OFF : $(cat test.dat| grep Cut_Off_Date | awk -F'|' '{print $2}'
```

We have seen few references in AWS wrt Named profiles. But not sure, if we can update the profile in runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Named profiles usually refer to AWS CLI profiles configured locally for AWS CLI or client libraries to use to call AWS APIs. My understanding is that you want to store/update some configuration file, so your cloud-based application can access it.

Quick thought is to use Amazon Simple Storage Service (Amazon S3) or Amazon DynamoDB.

[S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/Welcome.html) can be literally used to store/update files. It also supports version history.

[DynamoDB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/?icmpid=docs_homepage_featuredsvcs) is a no-SQL database. If your usecase requires higher concurrency in terms of config file updates, your might leverage DynamoDB transactions to avoid potential conflicts.